# Google Apps Script - Processing Form email as text

Tags: forms, email, object, google-apps-script

I have an App Script that processes a submitted Google Form. I'm capturing the email address (this is an education domain), which seems to be coming in as an object rather than a string. I'd like to convert this to a string so that I can extract the username before the @ symbol.

```
for (var keys in columns) {    
if (key =="Email address") {
    studentID = e.namedValues[key];
    var theEmail = studentID.replace(/@.*/, "");
    }}
```

How can I convert studentID to a string?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should edit your question to include what the debugger / Logger / Stackdriver report for the current value of  `studentID`. IIRC, [`e.namedValues[key]` is an array](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) If it's an object inside that array, it could be a [`User object`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user). So, use supported methods, mainly, `getEmail()`.

Comment: I would love to but due to this being on a trigger I'm not sure how I can gain the debugger information

Comment: Just add `Logger.log(thingy)` or better (exports to Stackdriver, where it will persist for more than one run): `console.log(thingy);`. I might use `console.log({eventObject: e, columns: columns, key: key, value: studentID});`, right after your `studentID = e.namedValues[key];` line.

Comment: The Logger.log is just giving me this: [18-03-23 10:08:23:443 GMT] [carrowsmith@thedomain.co.uk]

Comment: as you see in documentation and Logger output, it is an array. To get its values, you must index into it, e.g. `myArr[i]`

Comment: This is the solution: Where the line appears     `studentID = e.namedValues[key];`        replace this with     `studentID = e.namedValues[key].toString();`